# How to make div 100% with header and fixed footer

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the problem where I cannot make my content div take up all the space of the content area.

I have a fixed footer and static header.  The content div is actually inside the div from a RenderBody directive in ASP.Net Core MVC.

Here are what a couple of pages look like with the footer at the bottom:

[image]

[image]

So I actually don't mind that the blue content div does not come down to the bottom.  I think I can take it or leave it.

But then I created this page with a big image in the content div:

[image]

In this last pic you can see the image goes into the footer and extends the height of the footer element from it's orginal 60px height.

Here is my style sheet:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.content {
    background-color: cornflowerblue /*aliceblue*/;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}

.title {
    /*background-color: cornflowerblue;*/
}

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

/* anchor styles */
.nav-link, .dropdown-item {
    color: blue !important;
}
.nav-link:hover, .dropdown-item:hover {
    color: darkgreen !important;
    background-color:aliceblue;
}

.green-header-nav{
    color: black;
}
.green-header-nav:hover {
    color: black;
}

.facebook-anchor {
    color: #4267B2
}

.facebook-anchor:hover {
    color: #4267B2
}   
/* end anchor styles */
```

Here is my layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" 
/>
    <title>NeuroplasticityTherapies - 
    @ViewData["Title"]</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/Font-Awesome/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="row" style="background-color:black">
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="~/Images/dark-blue-brain.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 text-center">
        <div class="text-light" style="height:100%">
            <h1>Neuroplasticity Therapies</h1>
            <div style="border:1px solid green; padding:15px; border-radius:25px; display:inline-block;">
                There are answers and where there are answers there is hope.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    @*<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>*@
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-action="Index">
                    Neuroplasticity Therapies
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-action="AboutTheFounder">
                    About The Founder
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Functional Neurology
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Functional Medicine</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Neural Plasticity</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alternative Medicine</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Integrative Medicine</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Holistic Medicine</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Survey</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="row bg-info">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="border:2px solid black; text-align:center;font-weight:bold">
        Contact Us
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:2px solid black; text-align:center;font-weight:bold; background-color:black;">
        <a class="facebook-anchor"
           href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/NeuroplasticityTherapies/"
           target="_blank">
            Like Us On Facebook
            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="border:2px solid black; text-align:center;font-weight:bold">
        <a class="green-header-nav" asp-action="BrainMap">
            Brain Map</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

<footer id="footer" class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; 2020 - NeuroplasticityTherapies
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
@*<script>
    console.log(`footer.top: ${document.getElementById("footer").offsetTop}`);
    var footer_top = document.getElementById("footer").offsetTop;
    document.getElementById("content_div").style.bottom 
= footer_top;
</script>*@
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a content page with the blue background for "About The Author":

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AboutTheFounder";
}

<h1 class="title">About The Founder</h1>

<div id="content_div" class="content">
    <b>Gemma Herbertson</b>

    <p></p>
    Gemma has received training from all different parts of the world to include:

    <ul>
        <li>Institute of Neuro-Physiological Psychology (UK)</li>
        <li>Rhythmic Movement Therapy, JIAS (Denmark)</li>
        <li>Family Hope Centre (USA)</li>
        <li>Carrick Institute (USA)</li>
        <li>Kharrazian Institute (USA)</li>
        <li>Gillespie Approach (USA)</li>
        <li>The Neuro Science Academy (Australia)</li>
    </ul>

    Her approach is to work from the <u>bottom-up</u>:
    getting the brain to a healthy state
    (well-fuelled with nutrients and oxygen),
    and then providing individual neuroplasticity exercises
    for optimum effect.
</div>
```

Here is the page with the image on it in the content area.  The page is named "BrainMap".  This one is raising the issue for me.  I believe if there is too much content on any page I will run into this issue.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "BrainMap";
}

<h1>BrainMap</h1>

<div id="content_div" class="content">
    <img src="~/Images/brain_map.jpg" class="center" />
</div>
```

Don't know why I went down the road of color on the content background but I really want it now I think it is looking good.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the calc in CSS:
e.g.

if your `header height = 100px`, and `footer = 80px fixed`, then you can set your `content height = calc(100% - 180px)`

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Comment: Thank you.  A couple of things.  I think I read somewhere that calc() does not work in IE8.  Also, most of the example and fixes I get only work when the browser window has enough height. But if you shorten the height of the browser window enough the content merges into the footer.

Comment: Hi Sam, another thing you may try is, having your container with fix padding:

example:

.container { padding: 100px 0 80px 0; overflow-y: auto; }

and put your header and footer inside this container.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.content {
    background-color: cornflowerblue /*aliceblue*/;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    height: calc(100vh - 260px);
    /*you can change 260px accordingly to your needs*/
}

...
```

Here is the result of this demo:

[image]

Comment: Oh but on about the founder the blue does not go all the way down to the footer.  That's ok.  I can live without that.  I'll try the fix for the Brain Map page though.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sam, if you want to make the blue div extend to the footer , i have changed the css in my answer, you can also refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30793272/12884742